# Regex a wine directory in bash

Tags: regex, bash, wine

I am writing a small shell script that launches a program in my wine directory.
My challenge is that I have installed this on multiple machines, some with 64 
and some with 32 bit, some with English and some with Norwegian locals.

the name of the program files directory in `$HOME/.wine/drive_c` can thus change
from `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)`, `programfiler` etc..

The `bash` line I have so far is this:

```
(cd $HOME/.wine/drive_c/[Pp]rogram*/... ; wine ...)
```

However, the `[Pp]rogram*` line does not work, does anyone have a good suggestion?

Comment: What is it that "does not work"? What happens?

Comment: Please don't add "[SOLVED]" to the title to indicate that the problem is solved. You do that by accepting an answer (which you've done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work just fine, but since you will have both `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` on 64 bit installations this will always expand to `Program Files` which might be wrong in your case.

I would use the following to dynamically determine the correct path:

```
look_for='My Program/myprogram.exe'
for dir in "$HOME"/.wine/drive_c/[Pp]rogram*[Ff]*/; do
    if [ -e "${dir}${look_for}" ]; then
        cd "${dir}"
        wine [...]
        exit $?
    fi
done
```

This loops over all possible "program files" directories and checks if the file/directory specified in `$look_for` exists underneath it. If it does, it takes the directory component of `$look_for`, `cd`s into it and runs `wine` from there.

Comment: @Dan-SimonMyrland Apparently I made a mistake when copy'n'pasting since my explanation does not reflect the code snippet. To actually `cd` into the directory part you would want to do `cd "$(dirname "${dir}${look_for}")"` instead if `$look_for` also contains directory components, but I guess you have already figured this out yourself :-)